# What could be possible features of a textual word?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-cleaning, svm, anomaly-detection

I wish to construct feature vectors of words in a document and then calculate their linkage distance to detect anomalies. My question is how can I model these features ? If possible please give an example so I can understand better. Further how distance calculated will vary from the text that is anomalous and the one that is normal ? (Please refer to D. Guthrie, PhD. thesis for more clarification).

Answer (score 1):

That is a rather broad question. If you are on a document level, you could (after removing stop words) determine the most important words in your corpus by calculating the tf/idf measure https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf–idf 
Then you could define a vector over the top n words and represent every document as a vector of the relative frequencies of the top n words in that document and work on these vectors. 
On a sentence level that could work as well, on a word level obviously not. Anyway, information retrieval and computational linguistics are a rather large research area. Maybe the best way would be to start with a book that provides a good overview.

Since you asked for some more specific recommendations:

If you can get access to (or actually want to buy it), definitely this one: [Speech and Language Processing: An Introduction to Natural Language Processing, Computational Linguistics, and Speech Recognition](https://www.amazon.de/o/ASIN/0131873210/).

You can also take a shot this: [Sentiment Analysis and Opinion Mining](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/SentimentAnalysis-and-OpinionMining.html) this is probably not your focus, but it covers feature representation to some extent and is for free.

More like a handbook with practical approaches is: [Programming Collective Intelligence](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596529321.do), look for it at Google, it is also available for free.

Otherwise if you want to look for yourself for books at a library or so, your keywords are "Computational Linguistics" and "Natural Language Processing".

Hope this helps

Comment: What I usually find helpful for introduction and good references are open stanford courses. For Natural Language Processing, I found this one helpful: (http://web.stanford.edu/class/cs224n/) in the section Textbooks and Readings are futher good references to books if you don't want to go through the slides.

Comment: Would you please mention a book or two that might help.

Comment: I edited my answer.